# Add custom class to each page content with Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sass

I'm working with Bootstrap and using the same (.case-study.html) template for each page I'm creating.

I wish to add a custom class to the sheet of each, this would ideally be set in each page.

Any guidance on how to achieve this would be appreciated.

```
{% include header.html %}

<div class="sheet">
   <div class="content">
     {{ content }}
   </div>
    
   {% include footer.html %}
</div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap is a CSS framework. It has nothing to do with the generation of your HTML code in the first place.

Comment: (And `ssas` is an absolutely misplaced tag here. Did you mean `sass` perhaps?)